# Add-Printer from network location - Force driver installation UAC

Tags: powershell

I'm just creating a small script that will add all the network printers for users. There are 10 printers and 9 of them install successfully.

When manually clicking on the printers from the server, 9 of them install with no issue. The tenth one, when clicked manually, gives a uac prompt to install a driver. How can I get this around this?

Add-Printer -ConnectionName \printerServer01\Artemis

all the printers are being added as seen above

Answer (score 0):

This is why UAC was added, otherwise any program could just get around it without prompting you. The only way you can get past it is by disabling it in group policy, but it seems like you will be doing this for every single user and I would NOT recommend doing that as it opens up a whole can of worms regarding security.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to come on a network location and forcibly install your driver. Sounds like you allowed "Point and Print Restrictions" which will only work for point and print type situations in which most home setups won't be.